# How can I run a macro on multiple files?

Tags: notepad++

I want apply a Macro created in N++ to multiple files stored in a folder or multiple folders.

Comment: What is your macro doing? How many files? Do you need it to work for a long period of time or will the macro change over time/depending on the file? I've been in a similar situation, then I learned python and it solved everything. This is something that seems like it would be easily programmable but might be more involving using **just** notepad++. Give me any extra details and maybe I can help. I'd be willing to write the code for you depending on what you wanna do.

Answer (score 8):

You can end your macro by saving your document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and closing the window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

Or if you don't want the document to be closed, you can end the macro by changing the tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

I just found a simple and easy solution for that:

1. Make sure the macro ends with a Ctrl-Tab key
2. From Settings -> Preferences -> MISC, disable the doc switcher.
3. Open all files to be edited.
4. Use the "Run macro multiple times" dialog, and enter the number of files you have just opened.
5. Execute
6. Save all

I did not create this, found it here:https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/469ffec9/ , but it worked like a charm for me. I could edit 400 documents in less than 2 min.